# How to bind the json output from SOAP web service to UItableView using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got an following output from SOAP service. How can I bind it in `UItableView` using Objective-C (iOS).?

My code is:

```
-(void)retriveFromSYSoapTool:(NSMutableArray *)_data{

//converting values to array
NSArray *value = [_data valueForKey:@"GetDemoDataResult"];
NSError *error;
NSData *objData = [value[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

}

Output:

```
2017-04-04 11:39:26.499 SoapService[16524:545663] (
    {
    firstName = "1 Jhon";
    lastName = Macay;
},
    {
    firstName = "2 William";
    lastName = Proter;
},
    {
    firstName = "3 Joe";
    lastName = Root;
},
    {
    firstName = "4 Brendon";
    lastName = Haejoy;
},
    {
    firstName = "5 Jhon";
    lastName = Snow;
},
    {
    firstName = "6 Theon";
    lastName = Greyjoy;
}
```

)

How can I bind the above output to a tableView?

Comment: You need to show code. Serializing JSON has plenty of question/answer here. You just need how it works to apply it to your issue. Now, what did you print exactly? Is it JSON String inside JSON? It's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like JSON. You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert it into Cocoa objects like instances of `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, and so on. Then you take the usual way to fill a table view with it.